# Using transform translate to moving element

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a button that is in the exact center of is container:

```
.menu-heading{

  transition: top $speed;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

when is parent get the is-expanded class, the button moves to the top left of the page:

```
.is-expanded &{
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(.5);
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 9999;

  }
```

Now  I would be able to recreate this behaviour with transform translate property, instead using positioning, but I'm not sure if it is doable, with `top:0` and `left:0` I get the same result on all kind of resolution, with transofrm translate not.

this is the container with class is-expanded.

```
.section.is-expanded{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:1000;
left:0;
top:0;
oveflow:hidden

}
```

Comment: Please provide more code for referrence

Comment: I put the reference for the container

Comment: Percentages in `translate` are relative to the elements own dimensions, not parents.